# Getting 'Error trying to create the security policy' while trying to connect with mule dynamic cam online connector

Tags: mule, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, mule-component, mule-esb

I am trying to connect with mule Dynamics CRM online connector v-2.9.1 and mule esb version 3.8.5. After configuration when I am testing the connection I am getting below exception.

```
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Error trying to create the security policy
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Error trying to create the security policy
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.OnlineConnectionStrategy.createServiceForOnline(OnlineConnectionStrategy.java:97)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.OnlineConnectionStrategy.createOrganizationServiceClient(OnlineConnectionStrategy.java:70)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.BaseCrmConnectionStrategy.connect(BaseCrmConnectionStrategy.java:183)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.BaseCrmConnectionStrategy.testConnectivity(BaseCrmConnectionStrategy.java:195)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.generated.connectivity.OnlineConnectionStrategyDynamicsCRMConnectorAdapter.test(OnlineConnectionStrategyDynamicsCRMConnectorAdapter.java:27)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.generated.connectivity.DynamicsCRMConnectorOnlineConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.test(DynamicsCRMConnectorOnlineConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:447)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:88)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:113)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:68)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:1)
    at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:25)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:17)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:37)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 45; columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.utils.DynamicsCrmConnectionUtils.downloadUrlIntoDocument(DynamicsCrmConnectionUtils.java:228)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.security.online.MicrosoftOnlineAuthenticationPolicy.initialize(MicrosoftOnlineAuthenticationPolicy.java:73)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.security.online.MicrosoftOnlineAuthenticationPolicy.<init>(MicrosoftOnlineAuthenticationPolicy.java:65)
    at org.mule.module.dynamicscrm.connection.OnlineConnectionStrategy.createServiceForOnline(OnlineConnectionStrategy.java:95)
    ... 14 more

  java.lang.Throwable: org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Error trying to create the security policy
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the configuration xml is not getting parsed successfully due to validation errors.Below line in exception trace clearly suggest that.

> The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
>   ""

Comment: actually that error I coming when I am testing the connection .Hence I am not sure this is related mule configuration validation.

Comment: any leads/details of configuration xml you are using would help us to suggest solution to your problem.